# Help installing Ubuntu alongside Mac in an external drive (using rEFIt)

Tags: installation, dual-boot, mac, bootloader

I want to install Ubuntu on an external USB hard drive (in a blank partition already made in mac) and then use rEFIt to alternate between operating systems.

The problem is that, when running the instalation program (Install Ubuntu 12.10) I am asked the next: "Device for boot loader instalation". And I get the next options:

- /dev/sda ATA WDC WD3200AAJS-4 (320.1 GB) (Internal)
- /dev/sda1
- /dev/sdc WD 5000AAV External (500.1 GB) (External)
- /dev/sdc1

What option should I select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have one partition on the external drive (the one you want for Ubuntu), then go with /dev/sdc WD 5000AAV External (500.1 GB) (External).

Comment: Ok, i did so, but now, when I click Install a warning appears that says:

No root file system is defined.
Please correct this from the partitioning menu.

What should I do now?

Comment: You need to have a partition with mount point "/".